# How to set a java path on eclipse - Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, path

I'm trying to run eclipse , I installed the jdk then I installed the jdk with netbeans , I tried every solution on the web , but I didn't find a solution to my problem !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not installed JDK or not installed java properly.

Follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) to install JDK correctly.